# Get products by customer segments in Magento CE 1.7

Tags: magento-1.7, customer-group

I am creating a special page only for the particular customer group..
So, Regardless of category, i need to get the products those are having exclusive price for that customer group..

I tried with the following but it's not working:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_group_id', $groupId);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you mean a particular customer group?

Comment: Yes.. one particular customer group newly created.

Comment: not working? what are you getting?

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in /var/www/html/asterix/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php on line 816

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer by myself..

```
<?php

$id = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id'); //Customer Group Id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $collection->getSelect()->join(array('cpgp'=>Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getTable('catalog/product_attribute_group_price')),"e.entity_id=cpgp.entity_id and cpgp.customer_group_id='".$id."'",'*');

foreach($collection as $product)
{
    //Code Here
}

?>
```